# Resources$NotFoundException by facebook library

Tags: android, facebook

com.facebook.internal.Web Dialog.create CrossImage Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException I found this error firebase console. It says "Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to resume activity {com.bs.pulse/com.facebook.FacebookActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0800b4"

what actually does it mean? And how to solve it? One user crashed.